# calling one java script method and preventing form submitting

Tags: javascript, html, function, file-upload

```
 <form id=orders name="orders" action="orders_action.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="onTimeChange();
  ">
```

Here when the form is submitted if the time is in the correct range it should be successfully submitted and if its not in the correct range an alert message should be given using an `alert box(already done by using onTimeChange() function)`.The problem I am facing is that even the alert box appears and I press "OK" button the form data gets submitted into the database! how can I prevent it?

```
 var input =  document.getElementById('time');
                        function onTimeChange() {


                            var minTime = input.min;
                            var maxTime = input.max
                            var value = input.value + ':00'
                            console.log(minTime,maxTime,value);
                            if(minTime > value ||  value > maxTime) {
                                alert('Pharmacy is opened only between 8AM and 4PM!')
                            }
                            else{
                            return false;
                            }

                        }
```

This is the code for onTimeChange()

Comment: return false from your function

Comment: `onsubmit="return onTimeChange()`, and from within the function, true/false need to be returned. (If you really want to use old-school event handling methods … _current_ ways to do this would look different.)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use 'preventDefault' method from the submit event.

```
function onTimeChange(event) {

   var minTime = input.min;
   var maxTime = input.max
   var value = input.value + ':00'
   console.log(minTime,maxTime,value);

   if (minTime > value ||  value > maxTime) {
       alert('Pharmacy is opened only between 8AM and 4PM!')
   } else {
     event.preventDefault();
   }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try like this

```
    <form id=orders name="orders" action="orders_action.php" method="post" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return onTimeChange();">

      function onTimeChange() {


                            var minTime = input.min;
                            var maxTime = input.max
                            var value = input.value + ':00'
                            console.log(minTime,maxTime,value);
                            if(minTime > value ||  value > maxTime) {
                                alert('Pharmacy is opened only between 8AM and 4PM!');
                               return false;
                            }
                            else{
                            return true;
                            }

                        }
```

Comment: please check my function that i have put and help me

Comment: you need to specify return on  onsubmit="return onTimeChange();"